# Testing multiple iOS versions in Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

How can I test multiple iOS versions in the Simulator? I can only seem to test iOS 4.1. I would like to be able to test 3.x versions in the simulator as well.

Comment: Are you asking about checking the version dynamically in the code or setting the SDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cocoa with Love has a good [post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html) on how to do this

> To allow simulation in 3.1.3, you must
>   install an old version of Xcode. If
>   you are a registered iPhone developer,
>   you can download Xcode 3.1.4 for
>   Leopard with iPhone SDK 3.1.3 or Xcode
>   3.1.4 for Snow Leopard with iPhone SDK 3.1.3. Be careful to install these in a different location to your Xcode
>   3.2.3 with iOS3.2/iOS4 (either select a different hard disk or rename your
>   existing /Developer directory before
>   you install).

Answer (score 1):

In the "hardware" menu are options to change the device and the version.

Answer (score 0):

You can install several version of SDK in different path.

To download an older SDK :
http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html