# Is it possible to run iOS 4.0 simulator anymore?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios-simulator

I need to test a crash occurring in iOS 4.0 (not 4.3).

There's no simulator is there?

How can I test this version of iOS when the current one is iOS 5.0?

Comment: Possibly a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925407/testing-multiple-ios-versions-in-simulator

Comment: I think enough has changed since that post that it's advice no longer applies to this situation.

Comment: Especially for those on lion.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4.2 you can click on the Scheme dropdown list (near the top left corner of the window) and at the bottom of the list is a "More simulators..." option. Click on that and you are given the ability to download simulators for older versions of iOS. If that doesn't do what you need, maybe change your target's Deployment Target?

Comment: What are you just talking about ? Can you show that option as an image in your answer ?

Comment: I just noticed that the "More simulators..." option is only available if the target's Deployment Target is less than 5.0 (currently the highest option available). Once I set the Deployment Target from 4.3 to 5.0, that option disappears.

Comment: My deployment target is iOS 3.1 in the screenshot I posted and I don't see that option.

Comment: Sorry Christian, I don't know what to tell you. I'm not sure why you don't have that option.

Comment: Even with this "More simulators…" feature, it doesn't seem to be possible to get a simulator with an iOS version older than 4.3.

Comment: In the screenshot you clicked the scheme selector not the device selector. The button you wanted to click was on the right side i.e. iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

For that, You need to obtain the iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk folder.

The easiest way to do this is to download and install an **older version of Xcode** - the folder you will be looking for will be **located** in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/`

In **Xcode 4.3** on lion the simulator SDKs are **located** inside the `Xcode.app` in your applications folder.

**Copy** the obtained `iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk` into the

**new location:-** `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/`

**restart Xcode**.

I don't know if an Xcode upgrade will remove these files in the future - it might be beneficial to keep the older SDKs in a safe place in case you need them again.

[developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg)
 might be useful

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.3 if you click next to the Run/Stop buttons to get the Simulator drop-down, you can then click "More Simulators..." and download older versions of iOS simulator.

Here's a screenshot

[image]

[image]