# How can I use an iOS 4.0 simulator in Xcode 4.3.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.3.1, and I'm working on an application that is compatible to iOS 4.0.  I don't have an iOS 4.0 simulator option anymore though, and I don't see it under the downloads section.  How can I get a 4.0 simulator?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925407/testing-multiple-ios-versions-in-simulator

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not totally wrong, there is a "Hardware" section when the Simulator is running and in focus, click that and select iOS 4.0. If not try change the deployment target to iOS 4.0 (To do this you must change your apps deployment settings to iOS 4.0 or lower) .

Comment: You can use the hardware menu to change to any simulator you have, but I don't have one for 4.0, and that's the problem.